# Página se comporta diferente no Cypress ao tentar utilizar dois domínios em um único teste

Tags: javascript, cypress

## Procedimento no Google Chrome

Tenho uma página de login do Azure B2C, entro com o usuário e senha e aperto o botão "Entrar" e logo normalmente. Neste processo sou redirecionado para a página da minha aplicação com um token:

```
https://minhapagina?token=a1df6a5d1fa65...
```

Esta página é um WebForm com alguns `radios button` no qual tenho um botão para acessar a aplicação, se clico neste botão eu acesso a aplicação.

## Código Cypress

O código é bem simples

```
describe('Test B2C', () => {

    it('Login', () => {

        var testUrl = 'https://urlB2C...';
        
        cy.visit(testUrl).then(() => {
            cy.get('#signInName').type('usuario');
            cy.get('#password').type('senha');
            cy.get('#next').click();
        });

    });

})
```

## Problema

Realizando o processo manual, no caso utilizando o Google Chrome funciona normalmente, contudo fazendo o mesmo processo com o Cypress ao chegar no último passo que é clicar no botão da tela com os `radios button` sou redirecionado para a tela de login do B2C sem qualquer mensagem de erro ou aviso.

## Observações

- Se executar apenas o comando `cy.visit` para abrir a página e fazer todo o processo manual dentro do Cypress o problema continua.
- Se fazer o procedimento pegando diretamente a url `https://minhapagina?token=a1df6a5d1fa65...` dentro do Cypress funciona.
- Fiz a mesma automação utilizando o Selenium e também funcionou.
- A flag `chromeWebSecurity` já esta com o valor `false`.

Answer (score 2):

## Problema

Você consegue desativar a segurança do Google Chrome para aceitar redirecionamento para outro domínio.

[Set chromeWebSecurity to false](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false)

Mas não consegue trabalhar com dois domínios em um único teste.

[Same superdomain per test](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Same-superdomain-per-test)

## Solução até o momento

Criaremos então dois testes, no qual o primeiro será executado e enviará a URL do primeiro para o segundo. Assim cada teste trabalhará com um domínio diferente.

No primeiro teste acesso o primeiro host e pego a URL atual:

```
var currentUrl = null;

cy.url().then(url => {
    currentUrl = url;
});
```

Logo após monitoro se a URL é alterada, se URL for diferente da primeira salvo-a em uma variável:

```
var urlToken = "";

cy.on('url:changed', url => {
    if (currentUrl == null) return;
    if (currentUrl == url) return;
    urlToken = url;
});
```

Se deixarmos desta forma o testa passa para o próximo antes mesmo do redirecionamento, para isso implemento uma espera:

```
cy.wait(20000).then(fim => {
    cy.writeFile(tempFileName, urlToken);
    expect(urlToken).to.not.be.empty;
})
```

Dando tempo então para o redirecionamento e por fim salvo a minha URL com o `token` em um arquivo

> Esta foi única forma que encontrei de passar esta informação para o próximo teste, já que ao iniciar o próximo, todos os dados são zerados.

E por fim pego o arquivo no próximo teste com a URL com `token`:

```
cy.readFile(tempFileName).then((url) => {
    cy.visit(url);
    cy.get('#btnSelectLogin').click();
})
```

## Código completo

```
describe('Login', () => {

    var tempFileName = "tempFileName.txt";

    beforeEach(() => {
    })

    it('B2C', () => {

        var testUrl = 'https://urlB2C...';

        cy.visit(testUrl);

        cy.get('#signInName').type('usuario');
        cy.get('#password').type('senha');
        cy.get('#next').click();

        var currentUrl = null;

        cy.url().then(url => {
            currentUrl = url;
        });

        var urlToken = "";

        cy.on('url:changed', url => {
            if (currentUrl == null) return;
            if (currentUrl == url) return;
            urlToken = url;
        });

        cy.wait(20000).then(fim => {
            cy.writeFile(tempFileName, urlToken);
            expect(urlToken).to.not.be.empty;
        })

    });

    it('URL Token', () => {

        cy.readFile(tempFileName).then((url) => {
            cy.visit(url);
            cy.get('#btnSelectLogin').click();
        })

    });

})
```

## Problema da solução

- Fico dependendo do tempo configurado no `wait`, então se a requisição demorar mais do que o previsto não terei o resultado esperado e se a requisição for rápida terei que esperar de qualquer forma.
- Preciso criar um arquivo para troca de informações entre os testes.

## Tentativas de melhorias

- Tentei criar uma variável global, ela funciona se os dois testes executam usando o mesmo domínio, porém ao carregar o novo domínio todas as informações são zeradas inclusive da variável global.
- Tentei criar `Promise`, se coloco `await` o `Cypress` reclama que passou mais de 4 segundo ou se deixo sem, o próximo teste é executado faltando assim a URL com o `token`.

## Solução esperada

Seria ideia se o próximo teste executasse exatamente no momento que obtenho a nova URL com o `token`.

Comment: Boa resposta. [Esse issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1805) possui algumas alternativas à espera do carregamento da nova página, talvez alguma te sirva melhor. Esse ponto específico pode até mesmo ser uma nova pergunta, definitivamente é útil para quem usa Cypress :)